# Save IP and other visitor information in database using PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, ip

I am trying to store visitor information in database. I need to create a table if it doesn't exist, and then store information. But the information is not getting stored and I need help with the code.
Code --

```
// visitor information
$ip = addslashes((getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR)) ? getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR) : getenv(REMOTE_ADDR));
$visitorReferrer = addslashes(( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : 'Referrer undetectable.');
$visitorBrowser = addslashes(( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : 'Browser undetectable.');

// connect database
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","UNAME","PASS");
if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Create table
mysql_select_db("DBNAME", $con);
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `logs` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
 `brow` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
 `times` varchar(500) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";

// query
mysql_query($sql,$con);
mysql_close($con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'logs' (ip, ref, brow, times ) VALUES('{$ip}', '{$visitorReferrer}', '{$visitorBrowser}', now())");
mysql_close($con);

// image header to browser.
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");

// create image and allocate colors...
$im = @imagecreate(110, 20) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);

// IP text
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  "Hello $ip !", $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Still not working with the suggestion, (screenshot here)
http://0dae.in/cap1.png "phpadmin"

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

your insert statement referring to a column named 'ref',  which is not part of the table that you are creating.